# Message "error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'"

Tags: c++, include

I had a piece of code that was including some Boost headers. Upon compilation I received errors like

```
/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:1041:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert'

        BOOST_ASSERT( deleter_.use_count() <= 1 );

        ^

/usr/local/include/boost/assert.hpp:60:29: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_ASSERT'

# define BOOST_ASSERT(expr) assert(expr)
                                ^
```

These errors however only occurred on Windows and macOS.

Explicitly including either `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>` before the Boost headers had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out I had a file called `Assert.h` in my include-path (a custom file of mine). On case-insensitive file systems as used by Windows and macOS, this would shadow the original `assert.h` header that actually defines the `assert` macro.

The solution therefore was simply to rename my assert-header file.

(I found the solution thanks to *[[Compilation Error] error: use of undeclared identifier 'assert' #15](https://github.com/luckybulldozer/VisualSFM_OS_X_Installer/issues/15)*.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to `#include <cassert>` to bring in the `assert` implementation.

It's your job to define or not define `NDEBUG` accordingly.

I'm surprised Boost doesn't do that for you - are you using the Boost files correctly (i.e. including the files that you're supposed to)?

Comment: This work for my situation building bWidgets library